# Update table row after sending an email (Laravel Command)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a command which sends email to users according to their saved search terms. For now I have this:

```
public function handle()
{
    $user = Alert::select('search', 'email', 'interval', 'emailSentAt')->join('users', 'alerts.uid', '=', 'users.id')->whereNotNull('search')->distinct()->get();

    foreach ($user as $u) {
        $cl      = new SphinxSearch();
        $results = $cl->search('@*' . $u->search, 'spots');
        $results = $cl->limit(10);
        $results = $cl->setMatchMode(\Sphinx\SphinxClient::SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
        $results = $cl->setSortMode(\Sphinx\SphinxClient::SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC, "start");
        $results = $cl->get();

        Mail::send('emails.newSearchAlert', ['u' => $u, 'results' => $results], function ($m) use ($u) {

            $m->from('noreply@mydomain.com', 'My company');

            $m->to($u->email)->subject('Your search alert - ' . $u->search);
        });

        $u->emailSentAt = Carbon::now();
        $u->save();
    }
}
```

Here I have two questions...

1. How can I save the sending date and time for each user? I am trying to do it like it is shown in the code. `$u->emailSentAt = Carbon::now();` and `$u->save();` but it doesn't update anything... The `emailSentAt` remains NULL.
2. In my database I have a column `interval` (it is selected in `$user` variable). The value of interval is 1 or 2, daily or weekly alert (respectively). How can I make command so that it runs according to user interval preference? If it is daily, I want emails to be sent daily...

Comment: `$u` is not a User object. Try loading up the user object within your foreach loop and modify that.

Comment: I am not sure what have you said...It does not have anything to do with User. It is an Alert type object. :/ ... That column which needs to be updated is in alerts table.

Comment: Tried `$u->update(['emailSentAt' => Carbon\Carbon::now()]);` ?

Comment: Ah, misunderstood which object you were trying to update. Try logging `get_class($u)` inside of your loop, it may not exactly be an Alert object either.

Comment: @linktoahref I've tried it now and it says MassAssignmentException. After modifying my model and setting `emailSentAt` into fillables it doesn't show this error anymore, but still nothing is updated.

Comment: @linktoahref It is `\App\Alert` object type.

Comment: Is `emailSentAt` of type `DATETIME` in database?

Comment: It is `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I proposed you two alternatives:

- Add the `Alert` primary key on the select, and try to save again if that works.
- Try to perform an `Alert::find($id)` and then, save it, to see if it's working.

On your second question:

- You can have two commands, one that will run daily and another weekly, and each command you will retrieve only the users that have selected the interval related to the command, e.g. `DailyEmailCommand` only query for the interval = 1 and `WeeklyEmailCommand` only query for the interval = 2.
- In one command that will execute daily, query for all the users, send the email to the users that selected interval = 1, and check if it's the end of the week with Carbon and if that condition it's true, send the emails to the users that selected interval = 2.

Comment: Ok. First solution works perfect! I'll try the second now. What issue can be related with the primary id? It sounds strange to me.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, I just proposed you those two solutions to see which one suits you best

Comment: It is my mistake. I understand what you are saying. My expression was wrong. It should be "I'll try to solve the second question now". :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this using laravel

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$u->emailSentAt = Carbon::now()->toDayDateTimeString(); //date
$u->emailSentAt = Carbon::now()->timestamp; // timestamp
```

Using php

```
$date = new DateTime();
$u->emailSentAt = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```